# Rasterizing a plot make axes ticks invisible

Tags: bugs, export, ticks, rasterize

**Bug introduced in 9.0 persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

I've evaluated this code:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}];
g = Rasterize[plot, ImageResolution -> 300];
```

Everything looks good except the ticks (on the axes); they are invisible! It seems that *Mathematica* draws ticks in a default size on the scaled image, and after the image is scaled down, they are made too small to be distinguished at all.

The more `ImageResoltion` I specify, the smaller the ticks are and the less pleasing the image is.

How can I get the axes ticks to look right?

Comment: You've tried tweaking `ImageResolution` and `RasterSize` at the same time? `Rasterize[Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}], ImageResolution -> 512, RasterSize -> 512]` looks good to me...

Comment: Well, I don't really know why and don't know whether it's intentional but simultanesous use of ImageResolution and RasterSize have no use in my case, seems that Raster Size "kills" ImageResolution.

Comment: Current thread with solutions for recent *Mathematica* versions: "[Export high resolution figure causes missing ticks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51367/280)."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a hack that has some added advantages - in particular as a by-product you also get a vector graphics version of your plot that can be resized while keeping all relative sizes at the correct proportions:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}];
h = First@ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"]];

Rasterize[h, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

[image: raster]

The result has all the ticks at the same relative size as in the notebook. Moreover, the intermediate graphic in `h` contains the plot as if it had been exported to `PDF` and re-imported, i.e., it's a vector graphic but structured in a way that doesn't allow *Mathematica* to revise its tick marks etc.

Comment: A great trick:) One question: what can I do with axe/ticks color intensity of rasterized version? As I see that, if, let's say, I run this code: `Rasterize[
 First@ImportString[ExportString[Show[plot, ImageSize -> 100], "PDF"]] , ImageResolution -> 500]` I get image with preserved proportion but axe ant ticks line _width_ is not the same proportional. If I scale the rasterized version up to 5 times I see axes and ticks with line width as If they appear on default plot output. In other words, everything is great except the fact that axes and ticks get "transparent" due to antialiasing.

Comment: @DimG Thanks for the accept - as to the axis thickness, the problem seems to be that the thickness of axes and frames is by default given as `AbsoluteThickness[x]` and the latter isn't translated correctly in the `Export`. But this can be fixed by explicitly adding an option `AxesStyle->Thickness[n]` or `FrameStyle->Thickness[n]` to your plot. Here, `Thickness` is a relative quantity that you can calculate from `n = x/w` where `w` is the width of the plot. For some reason, these _relative_ thickness specifications are translated correctly.

Comment: @Jens: I used your suggestion, too, to solve a similar problem. I used `FrameStyle->Thickness[0.003], FrameTicksStyle->Thickness[0.003]` in my framed plot to get both the frame and the ticks in the right width.

Comment: This is great in many cases, but if you specify a font for the plot (e.g. to use the LaTeX font), then the initial output as a PDF removes that formatting and the rasterized version will have the default Mathematica font.

Comment: Hi, @Jens. I tried your solution on my plots in my post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172192/4742 . It seems that your solution doesn't support densityplot. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @matheorem  Yes, this looks like another problem for which I also had a solution. I'll post an answer with the combined code...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to regulate `ImageSize` together with `ImageResolution`. There is one example:
You get:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 250];
g = Rasterize[plot, ImageResolution -> #] & /@ {25, 50, 100, 200};
ImageDimensions /@ g
TableForm[Partition[g, 2]]
```

[image]

And yes, the quality is not as good as the vectorial form. Where we get:
[image]

I think that it's due different way Mathematica render vector and images.

Comment: First of all, ImageSize and ImageResolution used together  at the same level have no sense (seems that ImageSize has more priority), try to change ImageResolution and you will get no difference. You would rather have said something of: `Rasterize[Show[plot, ImageSize-> 500], ImageResolution -> 150]` However the main problem still remains as I've described: look at the axes ticks and you will notice **dramatical** difference between what Mathematica draws on the screen by default and what you get after Rasterize[].

Comment: I get your point. But just for curiosity, why you want that? Why use rastered form in your notebook?

Comment: Firstly I got this problem while Export[] (I have to make high-resolution .png for including in LaTeX). But then I found similar behaviour of Rasterize[] and since it's simpler to reproduce in Mathematica (nothing to do with creating files and littering the filesystem, everything is seen on the screen), I've chosen Rasterize[] for a question:)

Comment: Understand. Yes, you have to choose `ImageResolution` as `Export` argument too.