# Tick marks shrinking with ImageResolution

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-7

High resolution PNG export is handy for print quality plots, however tick marks are not scaling properly.  Does anyone know a solution or a work-around, preferably for M7 (on Win7)?

```
barchart = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}];
Export["demo.png", barchart, ImageResolution -> 300];
Import["demo.png", ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Edit**

It seems to me the best solution would just work on the ticks.  If they are specified explicitly they scale properly.

However `AbsoluteOptions[barchart, Ticks]` is not helpful for respecifying the ticks.  How can the intervals be determined automatically?

```
barchart = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, Ticks -> {None,
    Flatten[Apply[{
        {0.2*#1 + #2, Null, {0.006, 0}},
        {0.4*#1 + #2, Null, {0.006, 0}},
        {0.6*#1 + #2, Null, {0.006, 0}},
        {0.8*#1 + #2, Null, {0.006, 0}},
        {#1 + #2, NumberForm[#1 + #2, {2, 1}],
         {0.01, 0}}} &,
      {{0.5, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1},
       {0.5, 1.5}, {0.5, 2}, {0.5, 2.5}}, {1}], 1]}];
Export["demo.png", barchart, ImageResolution -> 300]; 
Import["demo.png", ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to export to `PDF` and get the proper tick sizing using `Export["demo.pdf", barchart, ImageSize -> 600, ImageResolution -> 600]` -- this could then be rasterized.  Is this of use to you?  Actually, since your question is focused on *export* I think it is, and that perhaps it's not a duplicate after all.  Sorry to have been hasty. :-/

Comment: Now I think the question gpap links to *is* a duplicate of this one, but as I was too quick to close before I'll wait for community votes.  **Possible duplicate:** [(14858)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14858/121)

Comment: @MRWizard yep, sorry - this is probably a meta question but can you quickly tell me the policy for flagging? I have twice now answered, then flagged for closing as duplicate/not useful etc. Should I have just initiated a comment discussion/flagged/downvoted?

Comment: @gpap it would be better to flag as a duplicate, especially if you are certain, rather than post an answer.  If it is not clear post your answer and leave a comment (preferably under the question) that you think X might be a duplicate.  Please do not down-vote duplicate questions unless the user appears to never show *any* effort to find existing questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok, thanks for clarifying - will do from now on.

Comment: The same question here with a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805451/tick-marks-dont-scale-in-graphics-why-and-how-to-fix-this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14858/rasterizing-a-plot-make-axes-ticks-invisible/14874#14874) by Jens gives your problem a working solution.

```
bc = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}];
barchart = First@ImportString[ExportString[bc, "PDF"]];
Export["demo.png", barchart, ImageResolution -> 300];
Import["demo.png", ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have no idea why the two "ears" of the first and third bars appear though.

Comment: This solution sort of works in M9 but not M7.  Also, in M7 the 'ears' can be suppressed using `Ticks -> {None, Automatic}`, but that doesn't work in M9.

Comment: I see, so the "ears" are ticks then. The above also works in v8 so I tagged your question appropriately.

Comment: This works in M7 with `First@ImportString[ExportString[bc, "PDF"], "PDF"]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible work-around sequence:

```
barchart = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}]

barchart2 = Show[barchart, AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.6]];

Export["demo.pdf", barchart2, ImageSize -> 600, ImageResolution -> 300];

Export[
 "demo.png",
 Show[Import["demo.pdf"][[1]], ImageSize -> 600 (300/72)]
];

Import["demo.png", ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, I settled for a mixture in the end: `bc = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
  AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.3]]; Export["demo.png", 
 First@ImportString[ExportString[bc, "PDF"], "PDF"], 
 ImageResolution -> 300]`