# Fraction Alignment in Plot Export to JPG

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

I've produced some plots that have fractional tick labels on the horizontal axis and they look fine.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], {-1, 0, 1}}]
```

[image]

However, when I export the plot with

```
Export["Graph2.jpg",drag graph picture here, ImageResolution->300]
```

the fraction alignment goes off.

[image]

Is there a way to keep the fraction alignment the same in a `jpg`?

Comment: What version are you using and how do you export? `Export["test.jpg", plot]` [looks normal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gt7sn.jpg) for me with v8.0.4 linux

Comment: Also looks good with V9.01  on Win

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and the command I've used is Export["Graph2.jpg",drag graph picture here, ImageResolution->300]

Comment: @keystonethewizard Yup, your output is the same here. Try ssch's command

Comment: And don't forget to start your comments with `@user`. Otherwise the addressee will not be pinged

Comment: How do I name the graph "plot"?  Right now it just exports the word as a picture. Sorry, really new to this.

Comment: Really easy `plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], {-1, 0, 1}}]`

Comment: Export["Graph2.jpg", plot] seems to work but Export["Graph2.jpg", plot, ImageResolution -> 300] is still funny.  Is there another way to specify the resolution?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14858/rasterizing-a-plot-make-axes-ticks-invisible

Comment: @ssch I marked it as a dup, because the same procedure solves this issue too. But now I doubt, because both _questions_ are quite different

Comment: @ssch  Using Export["Graph3.jpg", Rasterize[plot, RasterSize -> 3000]] fixes the resolution but brings back the alignment issue.  Did I miss what you were suggesting?

Comment: Something like: `Export["Graphics2.jpg", 
 First@ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"]], 
 ImageResolution -> 300]`  However you might find the `ImageSize` option satisfactory to avoid that mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14874/1517) for `Export` instead of `Rasterize`:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], {-1, 0, 1}}];

Export[
  "Graph2.jpg",
  First@ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"]],
  ImageResolution -> 300]
```

[image: output]