# Export high resolution figure causes missing ticks

Tags: bugs, export, ticks, rasterize

**Bug persisting through 11.3**

---

I understand that *Mathematica* has a bug when exporting images. The ticks are scaled not correctly when exporting at high resolution. For example: when you do:

```
Export["xx.png", plot, ImageResolution -> 360];
```

The image looks good, but all the frame ticks are all gone. When you do

```
Export["xx.png", plot, ImageResolution -> 100];
```

The ticks are there, but the resolution of the image is not good enough.

I tried the trick of using `ImportString` and `ExportString`:

```
ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"]
```

It works, but creates another problem: the `PlotRangeClipping` option is missing, and the figure has plot lines sticking out all the way to the boundary of the image, not the boundary of the axes.

Can someone provide an easy and relatively universal workaround?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805451/tick-marks-dont-scale-in-graphics-why-and-how-to-fix-this

Comment: Do you need it to be a rasterized image? If not, you can probably export it as a vector graphic (.pdf or .eps) which can scale to whatever size you need later, and then you don't need to define a resolution on export.

Comment: Hi. Exporting it as a vector graphic .pdf or .eps does work. However, neither of these are friendly with Microsoft, so I can't easily put them in the context.

Comment: My current solution is using export to PDF and then use ImageMagick to convert the pdf file to png. It's a bit walkaround, but the result is consistent. I wrote a small script so that it all works automatically:

Unprotect[exportFigure];

exportFigure[figure_,fileName_]:=Module[{},

Export["D:\\Documents\\temp\\tmp.pdf",figure];

Run["convert_Image.exe -density 600 \"D:\\Documents\\temp\\tmp.pdf\" \""<>fileName<>"\""]

];

Protect[exportFigure];

Comment: you can use Export["file.png", figure,"PNG", ImageResolution->360] of course you should mention what is your function and what is your command to create plot and after that you are going to export!!!

Comment: Try `plo = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, 
     None}, {{0, 1/2 \[Pi], \[Pi], 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, None}}]` and `Export["plo.png", plo, "PNG"]`

Comment: Without the code to actually reproduce your problem, there is no way to help you any further... please add all necessary definitions.

Comment: Adding "PNG" to export doesn't have any effect.

Comment: The code in question does not produce the plots that you show. Please post your actual code.

Comment: The PNG exporter is not scaling the ticks so they end of too small to see. A work-around is to export in PDF and convert the PDF image to PNG in an external app. I did the conversion in OS X's Preview app and got good results.

Answer (score 7):

The following workaround can be seen as an alternative to simpler and more reliable (but in some situations not appropriate) [workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104234/280) suggested by [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens). It is not perfect because in addition to being significantly more complicated it has several limitations due to abundance of bugs in `Export`-related functionality:

- `ImageSize` must be specified in `Export` explicitly, it is not sufficient to provide it inside of `Graphics` expression
- `Scaled` font size specification for tick mark labels must be provided via the `FrameTicksStyle` option in order to the default `ImagePadding -> All` behaving properly
- The font size of `PlotLabel` must be absolute because specifying it as `Scaled` reveals a bug
- I'm sure there also are other situations when handling of `Scaled` font size is broken and absolute font size must be specified
- The distance between the tick mark labels and the frame gets smaller when you increase `ImageSize` and there is no proper way to control this distance

The following is a way to generate **scalable tick marks and tick mark labels** for all types of plots using only built-in (but undocumented) functions of version 10. Please note that it works correctly only for version 10 and already includes a fix for [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57425/280) (tested with versions 10.2 and 10.3.1):

```
data = Array[# &, 600];

linearFrameTicks = {
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &}, 
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &}};
p1 = Show[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> Scaled[.02], Thickness[.003]]], 
   FrameTicks -> linearFrameTicks, PlotLabel -> "Linear FrameTicks", 
   LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 40, ImageSize -> 1000];
Export["p1.png", p1, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: p1]

```
linearLogFrameTicks = {
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &}, 
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &}};
p2 = Show[ListLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> Scaled[.02], Thickness[.003]]], 
   FrameTicks -> linearLogFrameTicks, PlotLabel -> "LinearLog FrameTicks", 
   LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 40, ImageSize -> 1000];
Export["p2.png", p2, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: p2]

```
logLinearFrameTicks = {
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &}, 
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &}};
p3 = Show[ListLogLinearPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> Scaled[.02], Thickness[.003]]], 
   FrameTicks -> logLinearFrameTicks, PlotLabel -> "LogLinear FrameTicks", 
   LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 40, ImageSize -> 1000];
Export["p3.png", p3, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: p3]

```
logLogFrameTicks = {
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &}, 
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}][##] &}};
p4 = Show[ListLogLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> Scaled[.02], Thickness[.003]]], 
   FrameTicks -> logLogFrameTicks, PlotLabel -> "LogLog FrameTicks", 
   LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 40, ImageSize -> 1000];
Export["p4.png", p4, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: p4]

Comment: Still works with V11.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I'll just put up this work-around - it's not perfect because the scaling of the ticks has never worked properly, to my knowledge:

```
list = {{{10., 5.}, {40., 20.}, {160., 80.}}, {{10., 1.83772}, {40., 
     13.6754}, {160., 67.3509}}, {{10., 8.16228}, {40., 
     26.3246}, {160., 92.6491}}};

myPlot = ListPlot[list, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Sample Size n", "Number of Successes: k "}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Large, FontSize -> 12], 
   ImageSize -> 6*72];

Export["plot.png", Style[myPlot, Magnification -> 1], 
 ImageResolution -> 360, ImageSize -> 6*72]
```

[image: plot]

This doesn't display very well at the small `ImageSize` that was specified in the question, so I tripled that size. You can adjust the `Magnification` to vary the relative size of the ticks. For this image size, a value of `1` seems to work best. It's counter-intuitive, but you *have* to include the `Style` command even though it seems to do nothing.

For a smaller image size, you should choose a larger value, e.g., `Magnification -> 2` to get the ticks to be visible.

Comment: (+1) Quite unexpectedly but it works (versions 9.0.1 and 10.3.1)! Actually `ImageResolution` does nothing here as well as `RasterSize`: the final size (in the sense of resolution of generated raster image) is determined by the `ImageSize` option of `Export`. This option controls the pixel size of the plot in versions 9.0.1 and 10.3.1 but unfortunately does nothing in version 8.0.4.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You're right - I copied the `ImageResolution` option from the question...

Comment: I joined others in voting to close this as a duplicate.  Assuming you do not disagree with that closure, do you think this should be merged, which will move your answer to that question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Of course, that's fine.

Comment: A magnification other than 1 might be preferable in some cases - see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129932/862)

Answer (score 5):

It is doof but it is working (I had the same problem):

```
Export["p5.png", 
 Import[Export["p5.pdf", p5, ImageSize -> 360, 
   ImageResolution -> 1000]], ImageResolution -> 1000]
```

where p5 the name of your plot

Comment: Yes! It works. Thank you!

Comment: Could you modify your code to a function, then others can use it easier?

Comment: This is great in many cases, but if you specify a font for the plot (e.g. to use the LaTeX font), then the initial output as a PDF removes that formatting and the rasterized version will have the default Mathematica font.

Comment: Per Aaron, I am getting characters in my plot labels removed or scrambled.  (Looks good otherwise.)  It is crazy this is still broken.

Comment: 3 years later, and it's still broken for me... I can't believe I just literally can't properly export a PDF of a plot I'm staring at.

Answer (score 4):

### UPDATE

Starting from *Mathematica* version 9 one can use comparatively simple [workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104234/280) suggested by [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens). For previous versions the only known workaround is providing manual `Ticks` specifications, see below.

---

### Original answer

This problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805451/tick-marks-dont-scale-in-graphics-why-and-how-to-fix-this) as well.

[Slava Nadvorny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139264/slava-nadvorny) suggests using manual [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html) specifications.  In this case they will scale with `ImageResolution`.

The [CustomTicks](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) package will make it considerably easier to create manual tick specifications.

Comment: BTW I believe this is a bug.  Why don't you ask support at wolfram.com about it?  If more people complain there's  higher chance that it'll be fixed.

Comment: I envy your optimism...

Answer (score 0):

I finally create a rasterized eps file with sufficent quality for my needs without losing the ticks. Maybe can be helpful even for other file formats outputs.

Try this double rasterization, where you can increase the ImageResolution value, but I do not recomend to increase the RasterSize beyond 515 or the ticks will disappear:

```
myPlot

Rasterize[%, "Graphics", RasterSize -> 500];

Rasterize[%, "Graphics", ImageResolution -> 350]

Export["myPlot.eps", %]
```