# Thickness of logarithmic tick marks

Tags: plotting, bugs, ticks, style, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

I'm trying to plot a graph wit a logarithmic y-axis. Since I'm exporting the graph to pdf and later printing it, I want to manually set the frame and tick marks to a reasonable thickness. However the logarithmic tick marks do not change their thickness.

(Note: I exaggerated the thickness of the tick marks on purpose to illustrate my point.)

```
LogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True,
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]],
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]]
]
```

[image: Plot with Logarithmic Ticks]

I'm working with Mathematica 10 on Mac OS X 10.9.4. In Mathematica Version 9 the logarithmic tick marks change their thickness as expected.

Can anyone reproduce this behavior? Is this a bug or did the FrameTicksStyle change in Mathematica 10?

Comment: I get the same (same system).

Comment: Same here, v11.0.1.0, Linux Mint 18 64 bits.

Comment: A duplicate question which contains better fix: "[How do I adjust the thickness of all the FrameTicks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155276/280)"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Reproduced in v.10.0.0 under Win7 x64. In versions 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 the behavior differs in details but the bug is also present: only *major* logarithmic frame ticks change their thickness, but not *minor* ticks.

Let us elaborate. First of all, in v.10 the logarithmic tick specifications are generated dynamically when the plot is rendered by the FrontEnd by calling `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks ``:

```
LogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, Frame -> True];
Options[%, FrameTicks]
```

> ```
> {FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
>     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}}
> ```

Here is what these functions return (I have shortened the output for readability):

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][1, 10]
```

> ```
> {{2.30259, 10, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
> {4.60517, 100, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
> {6.90776, 1000, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
> {9.21034, Superscript[10,4], {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
> {0., Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
> {0.693147, Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}}
> ```

It is clear that the thickness specifications are already included and have higher priorities than the `FrameTicksStyle` directive. That is the reason why the latter has no effect.

So this behavior reflects inconsistent implementation of `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` which should NOT include styling into the tick specifications they generate. It is a bug.

Here is a function `fixLogPlot` which fixes this:

```
fixLogPlot[gr_] := 
  Show[gr, FrameTicks -> {{# /. _AbsoluteThickness :> (## &[]) &@*
       Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, 
         Exp}], # /. _AbsoluteThickness :> (## &[]) &@*
       Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, 
      Automatic}}];

fixLogPlot@
 LogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]]]
```

[image: plot]

### UPDATE

Here is universal fix for version 10 which works for all types of log plots:

```
fixLogPlots[gr_] := 
 gr /. f : (Charting`ScaledTicks | Charting`ScaledFrameTicks)[{Log, Exp}] :>
                                                   (Part[#, ;; , ;; 3] &@*f)
```

### UPDATE 2

And here is universal fix for versions 8 and 9:

```
fixLogPlots[gr_] := gr /. f : (Ticks | FrameTicks -> _) :> (f /. _Thickness :> (## &[]))
```

Comment: Great elaboration of the problem. (In my personal opinion this is a clearly bug.) I'm wondering if there is a way to overcome the problem and change the thickness of the logarithmic tick without having to manually override the ticks with my one values.

Comment: Added a workaround.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Well, not entirely. It fixes ListLogLogPlot and LogLogPlot, but one cannot then do Show and combine them.

Comment: @Carl Can you give an example? It works for me.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov There is a lot of code, and, I do not own the data. Suggestions as to what to show, and how to show it, would be helpful.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, It does not work in Mathematica 11.1.0. ,May I know  whether you have some fix there?

Comment: @TM90 It works for me with version 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64. Can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: (+1) Got it to work by combining plots within a single ListLogLogPlot. Could not figure out how to use with Show.

Comment: @Carl It works for me, try: `fixLogPlots@Show[LogPlot[x^2,{x,1,3},Frame->True,FrameTicksStyle->Directive[Black,AbsoluteThickness[2]]],ListLogPlot[Table[{x,x^2},{x,1,3,.1}]]]` (checked with *Mathematica* 11.3).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be fixed in 12.1.1:

[image: screenshot of notebook]