# Longer ticks without specifying the ticks itself

Tags: plotting, ticks

I know similar questions have been asked here before, but i can't figure out this specific problem.

I have a lot of plots that i'd like to bring to a publishable form, but in my current customization the ticks are barley visible, therefore i'd like to make them a little bit longer, without having to specify the tick positions itself.

An example would a be a plot like this

```
ListPlot[Abs@Sin[N[#]] & /@ Range[350],
Frame -> True,
Joined -> True,
PlotRange -> {{35, 300}, {0, 1.05}},
FrameLabel -> 
Evaluate[Style[#, 30] & /@ {"T [MeV]", "\[Sigma]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \(0\)]\)"}],
FrameStyle -> Thick,
LabelStyle -> Directive[25, Thick],
ImageSize -> {720*GoldenRatio, 720}
]
```

I know i can customize the ticks by adding the following option

```
FrameTicks -> {
{
{#, If[Chop[Mod[#, 0.25]] == 0, Chop@#, ""], {If[Chop[Mod[#, 0.25]] == 0, 0.015, 0.008], 0}}&/@Range[0, 1.05, 0.05]
,
{#, "", {If[Chop[Mod[#, 0.25]] == 0, 0.015, 0.008], 0}}&/@Range[0,1.05,0.05]
}, {
{#, If[Chop[Mod[#, 50]] == 0, Floor@#,""], {If[Chop[Mod[#, 50]] == 0, 0.015,0.008], 0}}&/@Range[0, 350, 10]
,
{#, "", {If[Chop[Mod[#, 50]] == 0, 0.015, 0.008], 0}}&/@Range[0, 350, 10]
}}
```

which i adopted from some code i found here.

So basiclly what i'd like are slightly longer ticks on all sides, with numbers on the left and bottom.

Comment: I think the [CustomTicks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/CustomTicksGuide.pdf) package will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Works perfecly, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Virgil in the comments, the [CustomTicks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/CustomTicksGuide.pdf) package resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

In V10, you can use the `"TicksLength"` option of `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` to do this.  There is a bug/restriction, discussed in [Thickness of logarithmic tick marks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57425/thickness-of-logarithmic-tick-marks), that `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` will override tick styling.  So `myTicks` below will override the override and replace the default styling with the style passed to it.  There is another difficulty in that `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` does not have a `"TicksLength"` option, so to get unlabeled frame ticks of a desired length, I included that capability in `myTicks`.

```
Options[myTicks] = $myTicksOptions = 
   Join[Options[Charting`ScaledTicks], {TicksStyle -> Automatic}];
myTicks[type_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{stOpts = 
         FilterRules[Flatten[{opts, Options[myTicks]}], Options[Charting`ScaledTicks]],
       tstyle = OptionValue[TicksStyle]},
  Module[{ticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, stOpts][##]},
    If[type === "Frame", ticks[[All, 2]] = Spacer[{0, 0}]];
    If[tstyle =!= Automatic, ticks[[All, 4]] = tstyle];
    ticks] &]
```

A few notes on the code: If the `type` is `"Frame"`, frame-style ticks with no labels will be generated; other values for `type` result in tick labels (I used `Automatic` below).  Since we're returning a `Function`, we have to evaluate and inject the current options settings (with `With`) for them to have effect. `ScaledTicks` generates a list of ticks of the form `{x, label, length, style}`. Minor ticks come with `Spacer[{0, 0}]` as a label, so one could restyle ticks in all sorts of ways

Since we will have to specify all four `FrameTicks` functions, it is easier to deal with passing the options to `myTicks` with `SetOptions`.

```
SetOptions[myTicks, {"TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.02}}];
ListPlot[
 Abs@Sin[N[#]] & /@ Range[350], Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{35, 300}, {0, 1.05}}, 
 FrameLabel -> 
  (Style[#, 30] & /@ {"T [MeV]", "σ/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(σ\), \(0\)]\)"}), 
 FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 FrameTicks -> 
   {{myTicks[Automatic], myTicks["Frame"]}, {myTicks[Automatic], myTicks["Frame"]}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[25, Thick]]
SetOptions[myTicks, $myTicksOptions];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may want thick ticks:

```
SetOptions[myTicks, {"TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.02}, TicksStyle -> Thick}];
ListPlot[Abs@Sin[N[#]] & /@ Range[10], 
 Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 1.05}}, 
 FrameLabel -> 
  (Style[#, 30] & /@ {"T [MeV]", "σ/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(σ\), \(0\)]\)"}), 
 FrameStyle -> Thick, LabelStyle -> Directive[25, Thick], 
 FrameTicks ->
   {{myTicks[Automatic], myTicks["Frame"]}, {myTicks[Automatic], myTicks["Frame"]}}]
SetOptions[myTicks, $myTicksOptions];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What/where is this alleged package `Charting`? I'm not finding it with *Mathematica* 11.3.