# Thickness of frame ticks in a LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

I want to plot my function in log-log scale and I want my ticks to be thicker. The code I wrote is:

```
f2003loglogplot = 
   LogLogPlot[f2003, {x, 1, 50}, 
     PlotLabel -> 2003, 
     PlotRange-> {0.001, 2},  
     FrameLabel -> {"Wealth w [bil. USD]", "Π(w)"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], 
     Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Black, 12], 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003], Black, 12]]
```

However, my ticks don't change in width or height. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a known bug. For a workaround see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57425/thickness-of-logarithmic-tick-marks

Comment: It doesn't really work. It changes my x axis to linear scale. How do I modify  it to work?

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use? I have checked my fix with version 10.3.1 with your plot and it does work.

Comment: I have updated my answer in the linked thread with a universal fix for versions 8 and 9.

Comment: I'm using 10.3 on windows 8. Maybe I'm using it wrong. The way I use it  is like this: fixLogPlots@LogLogPlot...(... is the rest of my code).

Comment: It does work now. Miracle happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I post this in case it is helpful:

```
tk[l_, u_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Table[{j, j, {a, b}}, {j, l, u}]~Join~
   Table[{j, "", {c, d}}, {j, l + 1/2, u - 1/2}];
Manipulate[
 LogLogPlot[2^x, {x, 1, 3}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{tk[2, 8, a, b, c, d], None}, {tk[1, 3, a, b, c, d], 
     None}}, FrameTicksStyle -> {Red, Directive[Blue, Thick]}],
 {a, 0.01, 0.5},
 {b, 0.01, 0.5},
 {c, 0.005, 0.2},
 {d, 0.005, 0.2}
 ]
```

[image]