# How to modify the horizontal ticks in a LogLinearPlot?

Tags: plotting, style, ticks, logarithmic-scale

Using the following code,

```
LogLinearPlot[
 x,
 {x, 0.1, 10},
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3],
 AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2],
 TicksStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2]
]
```

I can manipulate the axes and the ticks on the vertical axis. How can I modify the thickness of the horizontal ticks?

[image: Plot of the code above]

Comment: it is known bug, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57425/thickness-of-logarithmic-tick-marks) for explanation and solution.

Comment: Great, that worked! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, thanks, we already established that..

Comment: @Stephan AlexeyPopkov voted to close the question as a duplicate of the other one, which causes the automatic generation of that comment