# Automatic Ticks on x-axis, but not first 5% of x-range

Tags: plotting, ticks

I would like to have Ticks->Automatic, but not have the Ticks in say the first 5% of the range on the x-axis. 
So like this

[image]

but not this (ticks too dense using regular tick interval of 1)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easiest to create the plot with automatic ticks and then remove the ones you don't want. Something like

```
trimTicks[g_Graphics, a_] := Module[{opt, xmin, newticks},
  opt = AbsoluteOptions[g, {PlotRange, Ticks}];
  xmin = First[PlotRange /. opt].{1 - a, a};
  newticks = Cases[First[Ticks /. opt], {x_ /; x >= xmin, __}];
  Show[g, Ticks -> {newticks, Automatic}]]

Plot[x, {x, 0, 100}] ~trimTicks~ 0.2
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to create an Automatic Ticks distribution starting from the (rounded/Ceiling'd) minimum value, like the x coordinate fo "12" in the top figure? Would make it even better!

Comment: I don't think so. Ticks are either fully automatic or explicitly specified.

Comment: @SimonWoods Actually `Ticks` also can be `Dynamic`ally generated by a user-defined function, please see my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, good point. I had forgotten that you could supply a function for Ticks.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are looking for something like this (code for version 10):

```
myTicksRange[min_, max_] := 
  Sequence[Ceiling[min + 0.05 (max - min)], Floor[max - 0.05 (max - min)]];

linearFrameTicks = {
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][myTicksRange[##]] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][myTicksRange[##]] &}, 
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][myTicksRange[##], {12, 5}] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][myTicksRange[##], {12, 5}] &}
                    };

Plot[3 Sin[x], {x, 0, 13}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> linearFrameTicks]
```

> [image: plot]

Note that with this approach you have `Dynamic`ally generated `Ticks` what requires `myTicksRange` to be defined when FrontEnd renders the figure.

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107473/280) of mine you can find additional information and also code for log-plots.