# Problem with custom colorbar in rasterized Grid

Tags: grid-layouts

I would like to create a plot made of subplots containing ArrayPlots with colorbars.

Since Mathematica's native colorbars are still a pain to be placed correctly, I am using an adapted custom one from this question: [Sizing cells in a GraphicsGrid/GraphicsRow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/sizing-cells-in-a-graphicsgrid-graphicsrow/2064#2064):

```
colorbar[{min_, max_}, ticks_, fs_, is_, colorFunction_]:= 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max},
AspectRatio -> 30,
ColorFunction -> colorFunction,
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]],
FrameTicks -> {{None, {#[[1]], #[[2]], {0, 0.5}} & /@ ticks}, {None,
   None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", fs, Black],
ImageSize -> {Automatic, is}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
PlotPoints -> {2, 100}
]
```

A minimal example of the plot I am working on is:

```
{is, fs} = {400, 20};
fsColorbar = fs;
plotops2d = {
 FrameLabel -> {"y", "x"},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black, fs, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
 FrameTicks -> {All, All, None, None},
 ImagePadding -> {{60, 10}, {63, 10}},
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, is},
 PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRange -> All,
 RotateLabel -> False
};

plot1 = Row[{
 ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {30, 30}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Evaluate[plotops2d]],
 Show[colorbar[{0, 1}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, fsColorbar, is, "Rainbow"], ImageSize -> {Automatic, is}, ImagePadding -> {{1, 42}, {63, 10}}]
}];
plot2 = Row[{
 ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {30, 30}], ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Evaluate[plotops2d]],
Show[colorbar[{0, 1}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, fsColorbar, is, "SunsetColors"], ImageSize -> {Automatic, is}, ImagePadding -> {{1, 42}, {63, 10}}]
}];

pic = Grid[{{plot1}, {plot2}}]
```

This results in this nice plot:

[image: still ok]

However, if I would like to antialias the image with:

```
pic2 = Rasterize[pic, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

I get:

[image: bad]

I can get the correct alignment if I decrease the values for ImageResolution or ImageSize. However, this is not an option for me. Does anyone what the reason for that behavior is and how I can circumvent it?

Comment: Does it happen with `GraphicsColumn[]` too?

Comment: Did your `fsColorbar`  mean to be `fs` (or *vice versa*)?

Comment: yes `fs = fsColorbar`.

Comment: @J.M. `GraphicsColumn` looks even worse. It crops more than half of the image for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Increasing Image Resolution on Graphical Elements

I suspect the glitch is applying `Rasterize` to the `Grid[___]`, as opposed to the graphical elements.  i.e.

```
newPic=pic /. Graphics[a___] :> Rasterize[Graphics[a], ImageResolution -> 300]
```

yields

[image: rasterized picture]

Let's first verify this does something. (Sure, by eye there's a change, but there should, e.g. be increased FileSize in an exported png, bigger ByteCount in newPic, etc.).

```
ByteCount/@{pic,newPic}
```

yields

> {89448, 150445080}

and

```
Export["/tmp/orig.png",pic,"png"];
Export["/tmp/new.png",newPic,"png"];
FileSize/@{"/tmp/orig.png","/tmp/new.png"}
```

yields:

> {23429, 95835}

So we see that our `newPic` has more data.

### Breaking it down

We apply the delayed replace rule: `Graphics[a___]:>Rasterize[Graphics[a], ImageResolution->300]` instead of rasterizing everything.

Looking at the man page for `Rasterize[]` we see that it indeed need not act on `Graphics[]` objects it can act on cells as you originally applied it. Yet doing so goofed your formatting. Since `Grid[_]` and `Row` were evidently formatting things to your liking, let's not modify *anything* that they do, but just increase the resolution of the interesting elements, and in this case all you really care about are the graphical elements.

We apply a delayed rule `:>` ( [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) )  because we want to match to data, then rasterize on that matched data.  We don't want to literally raster the element `a` or something.

`Graphics[data_,options_]` can have multiple arguments, so we want to make sure we collect all of them, some of whom could be optional.  The three underscores, `a___`, is BlankNullSequence, which grabs 0 or more options as available and sticks them all in the `Sequence`:  `a`.  Documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html).

### Working around the Tick Glitch

Rasterize messing with Ticks is evidently a known problem, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51367/51526).

The easiest workaround as far as I can tell is at the level of the plot generation so as to not aggravate the PDF import with the `colorbar`.

```
fixRasterize[expr_, res_] := 
  expr // ExportString[#, "PDF"] & // ImportString // First // 
   Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> res] &;
plot1HR = 
  Row[{ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {30, 30}], 
      ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Evaluate[plotops2d]] // 
     fixRasterize[#, 300] &, 
    Show[colorbar[{0, 1}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, fs, is, "Rainbow"], 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, is}, 
     ImagePadding -> {{1, 42}, {63, 10}}]}];
plot2HR = 
  Row[{ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {30, 30}], 
      ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Evaluate[plotops2d]] // 
     fixRasterize[#, 300] &, 
    Show[colorbar[{0, 1}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, fs, is, "SunsetColors"], 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, is}, 
     ImagePadding -> {{1, 42}, {63, 10}}]}];
picHR = Grid[{{plot1HR}, {plot2HR}}];
```

Comment: Fascinating, that seems to do the trick! Could you explain why that works in more detail? I assume since pic is a Grid of Row's of Graphics, any Graphics object is first rasterized before plugged in? I am not sure about the use of `___` accompanying `:>`. Why can this get to any Graphics object no matter the hierarchical position? Why does `->` not work?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to provide a little more detail.

Comment: While trying it out, I noticed, that the size of frame ticks decrease to the point that they vanish (for `ImageResolution->300` but not for `ImageResolution->100`). Is there a way around that, too?

Comment: Modified answer to incorporate known Tick workarounds from e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51367/51526).

Comment: To make it even more convoluted, once could prefix colorbar with `Rasterize[#,ImageResolution->300]&@` to get also an HR version of that part :)