# Exported plot range of PNG not displayed properly

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, import, image

I am tring to export the plotted graphics as PNG, but its range is not coming properly:

```
   linearFrameTicks = {
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &, 
   Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &}, 
   {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &, 
    Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &}};

px = 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -15, 15}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   ImagePadding -> {{30, 15}, {0, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, 
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 
     Directive[Black, FontSize -> Scaled[.015], Thickness[.003]], 
   FrameTicks -> linearFrameTicks,
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, All}];

py = 
  Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -15, 15},
    Frame -> True, 
    ImagePadding -> {{30, 15}, {20, 0}}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, 
    FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
    FrameTicksStyle -> 
      Directive[Black, FontSize -> Scaled[.015], Thickness[.003]], 
    FrameTicks -> linearFrameTicks, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, All}];

pz = Column[{px, py}, Spacings -> 0]

Export["pz.png", 
  Import[
    Export["pz.pdf", pz,
           ImageSize -> 290, 
           ImageResolution -> 1000
    ]
  ], ImageResolution -> 1000
];
SystemOpen["pz.png"]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Care to explain why you export as PDF, reimport, then export to PNG? Also, what EXACTLY would you like in your output? Your markings on the image are not clear to me.

Comment: @MarcoB, I want to png image of the plot, If I exported as a png directly then frame ticks not visible. (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51367/export-high-resolution-figure-causes-missing-ticks) I marked graphics due to it is coming outside the frame, that I don,t need.

Comment: What is the code about `linearFrameTicks`?

Comment: @cvgmt, I defined linearFrameTicks? in updated code.

Comment: @GopalVerma Exporting and then reimporting the graphic as PDF is the problem.  If you want a PNG, just export it as a PNG.  It is more efficient that way.

Comment: @ihojnicki, then frame tick in exported png image is not clearly visible.

Comment: @GopalVerma which version are you using? The ticks looked fine to me in 12.1.1.

Comment: @ihojnicki , I am using Mathematica 12.

Comment: @GopalVerma, ah.  In earlier versions, on Windows at least,  you could just do `Export["pz.png", 
 Style[pz, {"FontProperties" -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 1000}}], 
 ImageResolution -> 1000]`.  For the other platforms unfortunately, it would need 12.1.

Comment: @ ihojnicki , Thanks for your effort.