# ImageResolution affects the ticks on a plot

Tags: bugs, export, ticks

Let's consider the following example

```
S0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 550]
```

First we export the plot in a JPEG format

```
E1 = Export["tst.jpg", S0];
```

[image]

Then we export the same plot with more resolution

```
E2 = Export["tst2.jpg", S0, ImageResolution -> 400];
```

[image]

Here we observe two unpleasant things:

(a). The lines of the axes are light gray instead of black.

(b). The ticks on the axes are almost invisible or absent.

Is there a way to eliminate these drawbacks without losing the desired resolution (400)?

I am using v9.0 in Win XP Pro SP3.

The solution provided here [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14858/rasterizing-a-plot-make-axes-ticks-invisible) does not work in my case.

Comment: Also, IMO I'd export that as a PDF vector format, unless you need it as a raster.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli I need the plot in JPEG format without rasterizing it.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z - if you export as a jpeg you **are** rasterizing it

Comment: Hence the `ImageResolution` option

Comment: @Quantum_Oli, I would agree that it's a duplicate, but in this case Jens's solution looks atrocious: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XETmZ.png

Comment: @JasonB Here I used a simple plot. My real plot cannot be exported as an EPS because the size is more than 20MB. So I need a .jpg file with at least 400 dpi resolution.

Comment: Ah ok. The solution @Jason B provides below is a good one, CustomTicks really is great. You can of course manually specify longer ticks without having to download CustomTicks. I do tend to favour vector formats over raster where possible, if you're able to give us a more accurate example of your problem (eg, is it a ListPlot of 100000 points?) some of my code for exporting small high quality vector graphics might work.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Yes, the real plot is a `ListPlot` of about 100000 points.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this problem before as well, and my solution is to use the `CustomTicks` package, part of the [`SciDraw` package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/beta/).  The rest of the package could be great, but I only ever have used `CustomTicks`, and the number of times I've used it I wish I could buy the authors a beer.  Anyway, try this

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"]
S0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 550, 
  FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks, StripTickLabels@LinTicks}, {LinTicks, 
     StripTickLabels@LinTicks}}]
Export["tst3.jpg", S0, ImageResolution -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: First you download the latest version of SciDraw and then you extract the .zip file. Next? Where do you place the extracted files?

Comment: I believe you can place the folder `CustomTicks` in any of the directories listed when you evaluate $Path.  For me, that could be "/home/jason/.Mathematica/Applications".  I personally have a custom packages directory that I have appended to the path, which you could do easily enough

Comment: If I place them in C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\AddOns\ExtraPackages, will it be OK?

Comment: That sounds about right

Comment: It works but again the bounding box and the ticks are light gray and hardly visible. I want them to remain black.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did get Jens's solution to work via `Export["test.jpg", 
 First@ImportString[
   ExportString[
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 550], 
    "PDF"]], ImageResolution -> 400]`

Comment: I don't get gray tickmarks but I do get gray axes, so Jens's solution is probably the way to go

Comment: Also with the modified Jen's solution the ticks and the bounding box change from black to gray.

Comment: Okay, then make it black  :-)   `Export["test.jpg", 
 First@ImportString[
   ExportString[
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
     ImageSize -> 550], "PDF"]], ImageResolution -> 400]`

Comment: No luck. At least in v9.0 both of them (bounding box and ticks) remain gray.

Comment: Can you upload the result of this command to imgur:    `Export["test.jpg", First@ImportString[ ExportString[ Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 550], "PDF"]], ImageResolution -> 400]`   .  This is what I get:  http://i.imgur.com/vvArSmQ.jpg

Comment: And this is my output http://imgur.com/nl0t2RC

Comment: Okay, what about this:  ``Needs["CustomTicks`"]
S0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 550, 
  FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks, StripTickLabels@LinTicks}, {LinTicks, 
     StripTickLabels@LinTicks}}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  AxesStyle -> Black]
Export["tst3.jpg", S0, ImageResolution -> 400]``?

Comment: Exactly the same as before.

Comment: Right on, best of luck to you

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to specify `ImagePadding` in the first place then we can rasterise the plot graphics and insert it back into still vector axes.

```
    S0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 550,
     ImagePadding -> {{30, 10}, {30, 10}}]

    fig = Rasterize[Show[S0, Frame -> False, Axes -> False], 
      ImageResolution -> 100, Background -> None]
    axes = ImportString[ExportString[Graphics[{}, Options[S0]], "EPS"]]


    combined = Show[axes, 
      Epilog -> Inset[fig, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, ImageDimensions[axes]]];

    Export["test.pdf", combined]
```

[image]

This will allow you to export `ListPlot` with lots of points! The PDF of the below 10000 points is 60kb

[image]

**EDIT: Why do I have to specify ImagePadding?**

If I don't then the `Inset` graphics won't be in the correct place. I can't find a way to avoid this, specifically why does

```
   AbsoluteOptions[S0, ImagePadding]
```

throw error messages about `Ticks`? And why does it not return a value when `ImagePadding -> Automatic`?