# PDF file exported from Mathematica 10 is very large

Tags: export, pdf-format

In the earlier link "[Graphics exported from Mathematica 9 are very large because even standard fonts are embedded](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/graphics-exported-from-mathematica-9-are-very-large-because-even-standard-fonts)" was pointed out and discussed. Indeed, I met the same problem when I used *Mathematica* 9.0.0.

So I change the version from 9.0.0 to 10.2.0. Things becomes worse since the PDF file which was 5MB generated by *Mathematica* 9.0.0, is now 28 MB.

Can anybody give me a help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the graphic you are trying to export? Can you provide the code. It's quite hard to help without it!

Comment: Have you tried with `FontFamily`? See [Export to PDF on OS X, font missing on Windows](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45947/export-to-pdf-on-os-x-font-missing-on-windows/57936#57936)

Comment: Try to first rasterize your graphics and only then to transform it to PDF. This may help.

Comment: @Louis Thanks a lot for your reply. I have tested FontFamily in version 9.0.0 and 10.2.0 with Times, Courier, Utopia and Calluna Sans, but this seems does not work.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Thank you for the help. What I am doing is listplot the data that I have achieved using Fortran. I have uploaded the files to the google drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B386iQcR5L1yM0JlZDQxQnJmOXM . Could you please take a look? Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thanks a lot. Rasterize can help, but it will reduce the resolution of the graphics I think ^_^

Comment: You can play with the options `ImageResolution` and `RasterSize`. Have a look at the examples.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thank you very much. I have set ImageResolution -> 100, and RasterSize can minish the pdf file even from 50MB to 21KB and the resolution looks good. btw, I am also interested in how to solve the Font problems in MMA 9 and 10, in which I have been stuck for long.

Comment: If you're looking to export a `ListPlot` with many points but would like to keep sharp axes and labels, what you can do is just rasterize the plot points and keep the axes etc as vectors. I've posted some demo code for this before here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109652/6588

Comment: @Quantum_Oli I have tested your demo code, thanks for your contribution.  In my project, I have about 50 graphics which need the modification, so I am interested whether they can be dealt with using the Font setting? Best.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Supplement： most of the figures I am dealing with are generated using ContourPlot. ^_^