# How to correctly export image for grid of plot in high resolution?

Tags: export

For example, I have a grid of plot stored in variable `plots`

```
   plots = Grid[{{Grid[
     Table[ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 
         1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]], 
    Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "yyy"]}}]
```

and it is looked like in frontend

[image]

If I export it to jpg like

```
Export["test.jpg", plots]
```

The image looking is exactly the same as it shows in mathematica frontend. However, the resolution is low.

But I want high resolution, however,

```
Export["test.jpg", plots, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

gives

[image]

So my questions is

- **why `ImageResolution` affect the looking?**
- **how to export `plots` as high resolution jpg, while keep the same visual looking in frontend?**

---

**update**

I found even Jens' trick will fail for some complicated grid of graphics. For example, try below

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1];
plots = Grid[{{Grid[Table[plot, {i, 2}, {j, 2}]], 
     Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "yyy"]}}];
newplots = 
 Grid[{{Show[plot, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 2], plots}}]
```

and Jens' method

```
h = First@ImportString[ExportString[newplots, "PDF"]];
Rasterize[h, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

You will notice significant difference.

After tested many solutions, I found the most stable way to "export" to file and keep exactly the same looking as in front end and keep high resolution is using "save sections as" PDF for the whole cell. You can confirm that this is not equivalent to `Export["..pdf",...]` using `newplots` as test. Though an undesirable thing is that the output file will have cell tag.

[image]

However, this operation can not batch processing, if we want to save a bunches of files.

So I am wondering, **Mathematica do have a mechanism which can keep all the same looking when saving cell, no matter how complicated the graphics is ( grid, even grid of grid). There must be a underlining command that can mimic "save section as" PDF. Does anyone know the command to mimic "save section as" PDF, so we can do batch processing?**

Comment: Try setting also `ImageSize`: `img = Import@Export["test.png", plots,
    ImageSize -> 1200, ImageResolution -> 200
    ];`

Comment: Hi, @HenrikSchumacher, thank you so much. But I don't understand, it seems that even setting `ImageSize`, if `ImageResolution` is 600, the image is still wrong. Then why `200`? It seems rather arbitary

Comment: I have to admit that I also do not understand the logic behind it. =( Btw. I would store such plots rather in png. jpg format has the tendency to introduce these ugly block artifacts around lines and text. If you are going to print that, you while often have quite visible gray shadows around each line. png is lossless, so that would not happen. And if the images contain only few colors, png has still a decent file size.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you so much for your advice. But for smooth color variation like densityplot, it seems that jpg would be smaller for same visual quality : )

Comment: That's right. It's about smoothness of the original image.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two problems with *Mathematica* that come into play here. A solution that addresses them both is to wrap all your plots with `toPDF` as follows, before exporting them:

```
toPDF[plot_] := 
 First@ImportString[
   ExportString[
    Show[plot, 
     Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
       Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}], "PDF"]]


plots = Grid[{{Grid[
      Table[
        toPDF@
        ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1,
            2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]], 
     toPDF@Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "yyy"]}}];

Export["test.jpg", plots, ImageResolution -> 600]

(* ==> "test.jpg" *)
```

The result looks the same as in the notebook. The first issue I'm addressing with `toPDF` is the incorrect scaling of the ticks and frame for which I suggested the `PDF` export and re-import trick [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14874/245). The second issue is that this trick doesn't work properly with the `DensityPlot` output, but this can be fixed by triggering automatic rasterization upon export. I do this with another [earlier hack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18631/245) by adding an invisible textured polygon to each plot.

Comment: Hi,@Jens. Thank you so much for answering. I just found that the problem with densityplot is probably a bug. For example, `Export["density.pdf",plots]` and `Import["density.pdf"]` will also cause "Unsupported Shading type 7" error. What is wrong?

Comment: And an unexpected effect is that your current solution takes too much memory(because I set memory limit of roughly 3GB for mma, and it quickly blows it, so I notice the memory usage...)

Comment: and I tried to set ImageResolution as 300, it works this time. But look at the image, I found that the font size is obviously smaller...

Comment: You should definitely also set an explicit `ImageSize` to control the bounding box of the export. But personally what I almost always do if I want to preserve the exact appearance in the notebook is to take a screenshot instead of using `Export`, because it's not realistic in practice to always remember how to add all those options and wrappers... the other error you mention is related to the fact that MMA can't properly import its own exported `PDF` - that's why I added the `Texture' hack.

Comment: Hi, @Jens, Thanks for reply.  I don't understand "explicit ImageSize to control the bounding box of the export." What is bounding box? And I updated my post. Have a look? : )

Comment: I'm aware of no general solution, only partial fixes depending on the specific content - otherwise I'd be using it myself... The function of `ImageSize` is explained by @Edmund (and the problem is that the enclosing container changes when you export, including to `PDF` where the container is the "bounding box"). One other thing to try is: adjust everything the way you want it and then use the context menu (right-click) to save selection as... this could be OK if the notebook display has the resolution you need.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) option for [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html); both of these functions have the same options as `Graphics`.

The issue is that the default value for `ImageSize` is `Automatic`. This fits the graphic to the size of its the container.  In `Grid` this resizes the graphics when they go through the export process.

You may add any setting to the option for the the graphics. `ImageSize -> Small` or any other setting will work.

```
plots = 
 Grid[{
  {Grid[Table[
    ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, 
      Mesh -> All, 
      ImageSize -> Small], 
    {i, 2}, {j, 2}]], 
   Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
     PlotLabel -> "yyy", 
     ImageSize -> Small]}
  }];

Export["test.jpg", plots, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems working. Thank you so much.

Comment: However, I got a new problem. Check this `test = DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {"w", "E"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 13, Black]];
Export["iii.pdf", Grid[{{test, test}}], ImageResolution -> 600]`. It seems that font will be wrong, if we set LabelStyle. Is there a workaround?