# "Unsupported Shading type 7" error when importing back pdf for DensityPlot

Tags: export, import, pdf-format

This post is somewhat related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172192/4742).

We generate a density plot and stored it in `plot` variable.

```
plot = ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 
    2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All];
```

then `Export` it as pdf and `Import` it back,

```
Export["density.pdf", plot];
Import["density.pdf"]
```

we got an eror

> Import::general: Unsupported Shading type 7
>
> Import::general: Could not create shading pattern
>
> Import::general: Could not create pattern from /p5
>
> General::stop: Further output of Import::general will be suppressed
>   during this calculation.

What is wrong? How to workaround this issue when importing pdf back?

Comment: Try `Export["density.pdf", plot, "PDF", "AllowRasterization" -> True];
Import["density.pdf"]`. It works...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Thank you so much. It works